# Updating a label inside a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Here is a little background, I have a web app that searches large folders in specific portions of my network and stores them in a DB for later use. A second App will retrieve these folders to a grid and allow the user to Zip the folders based on a selection on the grid.

When dealing with multiple folders the process may take too long and my solution was to add a jQuery dialog that will display to the user how many folders are being processed and what folder was last zipped (or at least that is the idea) when is done a simple popup shows how many folder where zipped and if any was skipped.

**The Problem**
I can't get the label inside the jQuery dialog to update. All my code works and the app is doing the zipping but the dialog box is not changing. If I make a selection run and zip those folders and then go back and make another selection the label will display the updated content for the last run. Below is my partial code, I would really appreciate any advice and/or direction.

**ASP.Net code**

```
 <div>
      <asp:Button ID="btnZip" runat="server" Text="Zip Folders" OnClick="btnZip_Click" Visible="False" />
 </div>
 <br />
 <div id="dialog" title="Compression status" style="display: none">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpZipUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
            <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblUpdate1" runat="server" Text="Compression Started...<br />"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>

       </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,

            buttons: {
                "OK": function (e) {

                    <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnZip, "") %>
                }
            }
        });

        $('#<%=btnZip.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

and **C# code**
In the loop I process each folder and send it to be zipped then try to update the label.

```
protected void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... some code to get the folders checked ...

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedCount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            lblUpdate1.Text += "Updating a total of " + checkedCount.ToString() + " Please wait...<br />";
            udpZipUpdate.Update();
        }
        FolderToZip(strCkdFolders[i]);

        lblUpdate1.Text += strCkdFolders[i].Substring(Math.Max(0, strCkdFolders[i].Length - 4)) + "... Zipped! <br />";
        udpZipUpdate.Update();
    }

    ...... code to do final popup .................

}
```

I am open to suggestions, I have look at different ways to do this, like I said the main purpose of the web app works and I am just trying to make this more user friendly by adding a visual aid for the user instead of just leaving them hanging with an open page and no way of knowing how far along the process is.

Thanks you in advance for any replies.

Marco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an **AsyncPostBackTrigger** and tie it to **btnZip** *Click-Event*. Also **UpdateProgress** to make sure that the user is provided feedback if things take longer to complete. No other changes are necessary. Good luck!

**ASPX:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Compression status" style="display: none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpZipUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnZip" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdate1" runat="server" Text="Compression Started...<br />">
            </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">       
        <ProgressTemplate>         
            <center>
                <img src="../Content/img/CircularProgressAnimation.gif" /><br />
                <i>Zipping Files...</i> 
            </center>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>  
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, it displayed the progress gif and when it was done listed all the files that where zipped. Big thanks **Lucidgold**

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery UI Dialog in an ASP.NET environment, you need to use the [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option and append it to the form. I've found that not doing so causes all sorts of headaches (mostly bad ones).

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            appendTo: "form",

            buttons: {
                "OK": function (e) {

                    <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnZip, "") %>
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the **appendTo** option to my code, still I do not get the desired result from updating the label text in the dialog which is what I am really looking for.